# Accessing different Kinects with Openni_launch

Tags: ros, kinect, ros-fuerte, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I was wondering how I can change which kinect the openni_launch openni.launch file selects?
We have two kinects running on our machine and I want my program to use a specific one.

Thanks in advance!

Kind Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46892/accessing-different-kinects-with-openni_launch/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Martin! (it is funny to greet someone with the same name as yourself xD)

openni_launch has a parameter named *device_id* that allows you to select the kinect that you want to use:

```
<!-- device_id can have the following formats:
     "B00367707227042B": Use device with given serial number
     "#1"              : Use first device found
     "2@3"             : Use device on USB bus 2, address 3
     "2@0"             : Use first device found on USB bus 2
 -->
<arg name="device_id" default="#1" />
```

so, for instance, you can do:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch device_id:=whateveryourdeviceidis
```

I hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-10-26**:
I am actually having problem in making one device work..Only openni_camera package is working..Can you give me some suggestions on making Kinect work wih ROS Fuerte and ubuntu 12.04

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-10-27**:
Well... unfortunately the OpenNI driver is known to be not very stable on ROS Fuerte + Ubuntu 12.04. This *question* might shed some light: http://answers.ros.org/question/33622/openni_launch-not-working-in-fuerte-ubuntu-precise-1204/